# No dpkg or apt, no make or gcc. Need to install them all

Tags: apt, make, gcc, dpkg

I have a minimal Debian Linux based machine (i686) and need to get some .deb installed. This does not even have make or gcc installed. 
So I am unable to compile anything on this. 
So to get it started, I need a package installer (dpkg or apt). But I am not sure how I can install them onto this without the compiling from source. I am unable to find any executable as well.

```
$ uname -a 
Linux CryptoServer 3.2.6 #1 SMP Thu Jul 31 13:48:24 GMT 2014 i686 GNU/Linux

$ cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.2.6 (root@Build-CSLAN-green) (gcc version 4.6.2 (GCC) ) #1 SMP
```

No lsb_release command.

I should just ask the manufacturer for more details, I guess.

Comment: Interesting. How did you get this minimal Debian insall? If by booting from a CD or USB drive, is there a chance you can use that boot medium to install dpkg / apt?

Comment: So this is a hardware security module(HSM), and runs linux on it. I think for the security purposes they have toned it down to just the minimal functions.

Comment: And what makes you think it is Debian? Please [edit] your question and give us some information about the hardware and the system.

Comment: A minimal debian system has `dpkg` and `apt` already.  If it doesn't, then it isn't debian.

Comment: `cat /etc/issue` will often tell you what distribution you're on.

Comment: The frustrating part I am not sure about the "debian". I think it is. uname -a gives Linux CryptoServer 3.2.6 #1 SMP Thu Jul 31 13:48:24 GMT 2014 i686 GNU/Linux . There are no /etc/*-Release files nor /proc/version gives me enough information.

Comment: Then it's not debian.  Install something that you know what it is.  We can't answer questions about total unknowns.

Comment: You're not running a Debian and there is no reason to expect the deb to work. [Edit] your question (or post a new one) and tell us exactly what you need to install and why you want to install it. There might be alternative approaches.

Comment: You are aware that installing extra software on an HSM will void any security validation that it might have received, right? Are you sure you want to install additional software? Why? What software exactly?

Answer (score 0):

For broken systems I used the script below a few years ago. I you can get '/usr/bin/ar' (from binutils) to work, the rest should be not big problem (although it's not the best written piece of code…) as also the other programs should hopefully be there on standard systems.

*DISCLAIMER*: you should always check the extracted data.tar manually before running the script, as ist may overwrite important files if you are unlucky.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Try to install given package name without apt or similar helpers.
# It's a kind of 'quick and dirty' but usefull if system broke down.
#


TMPBASEPATH=~/.tmp


TMPPATH=$TMPBASEPATH/$2

echo;echo -=] Please start this script in a directory with rights to write 
echo -=] with the path of the .deb file which should be installed as first
echo -=] and the name \(only the name without \'.deb\'\) of the .deb file as 
echo -=] second argument.
echo -=] Sample: 
echo -=] \'$0 /cdrom/pool/main/a/apt apt_0.5.4_i386\'

echo; echo -=] First argument has been: \'$1\'
echo -=] Second argument has been: \'$2\'
echo -=] Trying to install \'$1/$2.deb\'

echo; echo -=] Creating directory \'$TMPPATH\'
mkdir $TMPPATH -p

echo -=] Copying \'$1/$2.deb\' to \'$TMPPATH\'
cp $1/$2.deb $TMPPATH

echo -=] Unpacking from Debian archive \'$TMPPATH/$2.deb\'
ar xv $TMPPATH/$2.deb data.tar.gz

echo -=] Unpacking from gzip archive \'./data.tar.gz\'
gunzip ./data.tar.gz -v

echo -=] Moving \'./data.tar\' to directory \'/\'
mv ./data.tar /$2.tar

echo -=] Entering directory \'/\'
cd /

echo -=] Unpacking tar archive \'/$2.tar\'
tar -xvf /$2.tar

echo; echo -=] Removing \'/$2.tar\'
rm /$2.tar


echo -=] All done!
echo
```